# Django custom field change not detected by migrations

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-migrations, django-database

I have multiple custom fields in Django. First, they extended `PositiveSmallIntegerField` as we used int choices like:

```
class BusinessLegalFormField(models.PositiveSmallIntegerField):
    choices = [(1,'SRO'), (2, ....]

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not args or not args[0]:
            kwargs.setdefault('verbose_name', 'Právna forma')

        kwargs['choices'] = self.choices
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Then I changed it to `CharField` and `TextChoices`:

```
class BusinessLegalFormField(models.CharField):
    class Choices(models.TextChoices):
        ZIVNOST = 'zivnost', 'Živnosť'
        SRO = 'sro', 'Spoločnosť s ručením obmedzeným'
        AS = 'as', 'Akciová spoločnosť'

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not args or not args[0]:
            kwargs.setdefault('verbose_name', 'Právna forma')
        kwargs.setdefault('max_length', 64)
        kwargs['choices'] = self.Choices.choices
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

The problem is that I just realized that Django didn't detect the type change. When I change something like `null=True` to `null=False` it is detected, but the DB type is not changed from number to char.

How can I make it work?

Comment: https://www.django-antipatterns.com/troubleshooting/a-certain-field-does-not-appear-in-the-migrations-and-in-the-database-table.html, this can be helpful for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This very situation, and the solution for it, is [described in the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/custom-model-fields/#changing-a-custom-field-s-base-class):

> You can’t change the base class of a custom field because Django won’t detect the change and make a migration for it... You must create a new custom field class and update your models to reference it.
>
> ```
> class CustomCharField(models.CharField):
>     ...
>
> class CustomTextField(models.TextField):
>     ...
> ```